# ajax query without passing page data laravel 5.6

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have a button and when it's clicked, I basically want to load the Auth::user()->name and a date into the database. I can't figure out how to do an ajax call without passing in some sort of data. This is my ajax query.

```
var url2 = "/application-background-sent/{{$application->id}}";
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#bgSubmit').click(function(e){
                 $.ajax({
                          url: url2,
                          success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                          },
                          type: 'GET'
                       });
                     });
                  });
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/application-background-sent/{id}', 'ApplicationsController@backgroundSent');
```

My controller:

```
  public function backgroundSent($id)
    {
      $application = Application::findOrFail($id);
      $application->bg_check_submitted_by = Auth::user()->name;
      $application->save();
      return response()->json(['success'=>'Data is successfully added']);
    }
```

Comment: please use `debugger` or `console.log` instead of `alert`

Comment: The console log gives me a 500 internal server error

Comment: you should also be using `POST|PUT` for this otherwise people could easily cause this request on someone who doesn't want to do it

Comment: but the issue is with auth somehow, the code should technically work if you have authentication setup so that ajax can use it

Comment: Check `laravel.log` for an error. 500 error messages would be stored in laravel.log

Comment: Ok. So i can check laravel log. Other than that, the code looks good? I'm not missing something obvious am i?